# Как отправить uid карты Rfid -а в другой Arduino расположена в расстояние боле 500 метров

Tags: arduino

Как передать данные карты UID RFID на другой Arduino расположенный на расстоянии более 500 метров?

- Wi-fi не подходит;
- Ethernet shield не подходит;
- Радио модуль тоже; (RFID расположена внутри помещения)

Comment: Форум немного не профильный, и в вопросе нехватает информации(например расстояние и объем передаваемых данных)

Comment: NRF24l01+ с усилителем, в прямой видимости до километра(по заявлениям разработчиков, реально тестировал 400м).

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Почему Wifi, Ethernet и RF не подходят? Нужна беспроводная или проводная передача данных? Устройства находятся в прямой области видимости друг друга?

Comment: Устройства не находятся в прямой видимости.

Comment: Wifi  в 500 метров не работает стабильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Предположу что вопрос исходит от [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884767/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-rfid-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-500-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-arduino).*

Для подключения нескольких RFID модулей к одному шлюзу (Arduino) на расстоянии более 500 метров можно применить несколько методов:

- **RS232** шина позволит подключить Arduino к модулям на расстоянии более 100 m. При применении витой пары и достаточно низкой скорости передачи данных (а так же алгоритма обнаружения ошибок) вероятно получить надёжную (хоть и медленную) связть на расстоянии 500 метров. Для достижения большей скорости и надёжности можно так же использовать RS232 повторители. 
  Цена подобного решения около $2 за каждый конвертер TTL -> RS232 (по 2 на каждый модуль), стоимость витой пары и $35+ за каждый повторитель (при необходимости). *Стоит однако учитывать что 500 m достатончо большое расстояние и это не обязательно будет надёжно работать.*
- **Ethernet** или **Wi-Fi** можно использовать для подключения каждого модуля к интернету (через промежуточный шлюз) для общения с основным шлюзом (*как на картинке ниже*).
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
  В данном случае расстояние между RFID модулями и Arduino шлюзом никак не ограничено, одноко требуется доступ к интернету на обоих концах.
- **GSM** сеть можно использовать в случае если нет возможности подключить оба конца к интернету.
  [image]
  Способ подключения схож с Ethernet и Wi-Fi но не требует подключения к интернету. Придётся однако оплачивать трафик.
- **RF модуль** на подобии NRF24l01+ согласно спецификации может работать на расстоянии до 1000 м, чего вполне можно достичь с помощью хороших антен. Оптимальныйй способ подключения так же предполагает использование промежуточного шлюза, как и в двух предыдущих примерах. Возможно так же использовать LoRa или ZigBee (Pro серия) что бы получить большее расстояние, однако стоят они дороже и расчитаны на расстояния от 1000 м.

По ситуации, можно применить один из способов выше или комбинировать несколько. К пр. для увеличения пробивной способности RF модуля можно поместить промужеточный шлюз (с RF передатчиком) на крышу здания и подключить к нему RFID модули через RS232 шину.